# Cannot send UDID from iPhone to PHP to MySQL database

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having difficulties sending the UDID from the iPhone to a PHP script to my MySQL database. I am not having a problem POSTing the data to the PHP script, but for some reason the PHP is not putting it into the database. I have tried entering "12343214312" as my example UDID and thats working, but the actual UDID is not for some reason. Is it some formatting mistake I am making?

Here is my code for the PHP:

```
<?php

    $udidfromiphone = $_POST['udidfromiphone'];
    //Connect To Database
    $hostname='HOSTNAME.db.7774297.hostedresource.com';
    $username='USERNAME';
    $password='PASSWORD';
    $dbname='DBNAME';

    mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

$query = "INSERT INTO mydatabase VALUES ($udidfromiphone,'7')";
    echo "Values added";
    mysql_query($query);


     mysql_close();   
?>
```

In my MySQL, I have two fields, one for UDID which is a varchar(60) and another field which is an integer.

Thanks!!

Comment: have you checked the `$udidfromiphone` this value from `$_POST` , is it coming or not ?

Comment: one more thing `$Udidtest` from where you are getting value in this variable ? is it typo for `$udidfromiphone`

Comment: yes, that value is coming in perfectly. the problem is that its not getting stored in the database. I even tried to add the UDID manually, directly with PHP, and that didn't work either.

Comment: ya sorry that was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> INSERT INTO mydatabase VALUES ($udidfromiphone,'7')
> ```

When trying this with a number, the query becomes like this:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase VALUES (12345678,'7')
```

That's valid SQL. A UDID consists of letters and numbers though, so the query will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase VALUES (ABCDE12345FGHI,'7')
```

That's not correct SQL. **Quote your strings:**

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase VALUES ('$udidfromiphone','7')
```

Furthermore, this is prone to SQL injection. **Escape your values.** Google for "SQL injection", there's a ton of material about it out there.